# tow jtextfiled Addition to another Jtextfilde immeditly without action button

Tags: jtextfield

I create Jframe with 3 Jtextfield

1-first value

2-second value

3-result

I need make operation between first value and second value to result without any button 
just once I insert number in the second value the result show immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DocumentListener` in `JTextField` document to catch events. 
the document is taken to `JTextField::getDocument()`